# Responsive Site in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive site : [here](http://45.55.92.53/)

**My goal** is embed that site into an iframe, and still keeping the responsiveness.

I’ve tried testing embed my site in JSFiddle as a sample : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/m7L5sp4e/)

---

My form look extended on a phone screen

[image]

---

My goal is to achieve something like this image above

[image]

---

I’ve use everything I got in my responsive knowledge toolbox. 
I’ve use bootrap grid system (`col-xs-12`). 
I also tried placing this on top of my HTML page

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

I hope someone can filling out what I missed here

Comment: I try to resize the windows at js fiddle and your page is already responsive http://awesomescreenshot.com/07b5gvcvbf . Have you try it using a html file then load it at your phone?

Comment: Try viewing it : [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/m7L5sp4e/show/) on your phone. You will see what I am seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
iframe {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://45.55.92.53/"></iframe>
```

Comment: How would I go about and test this on my phone ?

Comment: herrh, Thanks, What is height 100% and margin 0 do ? If I want to embed this iframe as part of the page, not the whole page, will I still be able to use your suggestion ?

Comment: Not without javascript. But here is a [quick example](http://jsbin.com/pigezosuko/edit?html,css,js,output). Don't forget to click on "run with js".

Answer (score 1):

I try to create it as html file and load it from my phone. THe responsive working good. So the issue is in jsfiddle rendering, not in your code.

Comment: Do you mean the iframe or the site ?

Comment: yes, try to create html file and put this code <iframe src="http://45.55.92.53/"></iframe> . Then open it from your phone